# Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: Value for attr 'T' of int64 is not in the list of allowed values: float, int32

Tags: typeerror

I have saved model using tf.train.Saver.save() and then freeze the graph bu using below method:

```
def freezeModel(modelName):
    input_graph_path = modelName + '.pb'
    checkpoint_path = './' + modelName + '.ckpt'
    input_saver_def_path = ""
    input_binary = True
    output_node_names = "x_indices,x_values,x_dense_shape,unary_scores,transition_params,train_op"
    restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
    filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
    output_frozen_graph_name = 'frozen_' + modelName + '.pb'

    clear_devices = True

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path,input_saver_def_path,input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices, "")
    return
```

**Then loading the modelName.pb file in Android using inference api as below:**

```
TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface = new **TensorFlowInferenceInterface**(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
```

I am getting **below error**:
Caused by:

```
java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: Value for attr 'T' of int64 is not in the list of allowed values: float, int32**
; NodeDef: Less_1 = Less[T=DT_INT64](ToInt64_2, ToInt64_3); Op<name=Less; signature=x:T, y:T -> z:bool; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32]>
at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.loadGraph(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:439)
at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.<init>(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:98)
```

**Here is the code using to create the graph:**

```
x_indices_t= tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, 3), name="x_indices")
x_values_t= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None), name="x_values")
x_dense_shape_t= tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(3), name="x_dense_shape")#[len(X_train), max_word_count, feature_count]
shape_unary_score_t = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(None, None, None), name="shape_unary_score")#[num_examples_t, max_word_count, num_tags]
shape_t = tf.shape(shape_unary_score_t)

x_t = tf.SparseTensor(indices=x_indices, values=x_values, dense_shape=x_dense_shape)
```

**To resolve above error i changed the dtype of indices and shapes to int32 then tf.SparseTensor() is givving below error:

```
File "CRF_POS_Trainer_Tensor - Training.py", line 323, in <module>
    x_t = tf.SparseTensor(indices=x_indices_t, values=x_values_t, dense_shape=x_dense_shape_t)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py", line 119, in _init_
    indices, name="indices", dtype=dtypes.int64)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 741, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 614, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    % (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
**ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("x_indices:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=int32)'
```

So how to I resolve the issue to create SparseTensor with int32 data.

**Tensorflow Version: 1.3.0**

Comment: Hello. Do you found the answer?